# Comment expliquer l'origine de ce « de » dans l'expression « comme si de rien n'était » ?

Tags: expressions, usage, histoire, origine-ou-raison

Le sens de l'expression, *comme si rien ne s'était passé*, est relativement clair pour quiconque a déjà rencontré l'expression en situation, mais pourquoi cette forme étrange ? Savez-vous d'où vient cette construction particulière avec un « de » qui semble superflu ? Pourquoi l'usage n'a-t-il pas penché en faveur du plus simple et plus court *comme si rien n'était* ?

Merci pour vos avis éclairés.

Comment: Peut-être l'original était-il "Comme s'il ne s'agissait de rien" ou quelque chose dans le genre...

Comment: En tout cas, le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_si_de_rien_n%E2%80%99%C3%A9tait) sèche lui aussi...

Comment: @Alexis J'avais moi aussi le sentiment que l'expression était le résultat d'une contraction, sans parvenir à savoir laquelle. Mystère...

Comment: Il y a un peu d'explications [ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic13346-comme-si-de-rien-netait.html) mais pas de réponse complète.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il me semble que :

- L’expression figée « *comme si de rien n’était* » ou « *comme si rien ne s’était passé* » date du 17<sup>e</sup>. Elle était écrite en italique à l'époque car les gens la trouvaient familière. C'est le cas de Balzac (*Ursule Mirouët, IV*) ou Gide (*Journal*, 25 oct. 1938).
- *Comme si rien n'était* existe, mais est désuet.
- Certains grammairiens voient ce *de* comme un sujet, d'autres comme un attribut. Mais c'est la première qui est manifestement la plus favorisée.
- Le *de* sert à indiquer que l'expression est une situation particulière et non pas prise dans le sens « comme si rien n'existait » (R. Martin, *Le mot « rien » et ses concurrents en français*, 1966).

Comment: (+1) La réponse est excellente, mais si jamais tu avais une source, un lien ou une référence sous la main pour étayer le propos, ça me déciderait plus vite à accepter la réponse expressément...

Comment: J'ai trouvé cela en farfouillant sur internet et j'ai essayé de le regrouper. Mais mes connaissances n'ont pas cette portée. J'ai édité la réponse pour ajouter des sources.

Comment: @Xaltar: SVP, pourriez-vous éclaircir la raison pour laquelle on interpréterait, encore moins certains grammairiens, ce *de* comme un sujet"? Je ne le pige pas.

Answer (score 5):

Le TLFi inclut dans [la section étymologique de *rien*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rien) une ancienne expression, quoique la connexion étymologique laisse à désirer:

> loc. adv. ca 1160 *ne ... de rien* « en aucune manière, nullement » (*Eneas*, 1821: Quant il de rien ne me conforte); 1377 *ne ... en rien* « id. » (Gace de La Buigne, *Deduis*, 1554 ds T.-L.).

Par ailleurs, on ne peut pas ajouter *de* dans ta phrase-exemple (**comme si de rien ne s'était passé*), au même titre que **comme si rien n'était* est incorrect. La tournure avec *de* a donc probablement eu un sens précis à une certaine époque. Je note que d'autres expressions vieillies sont citées avec *de*: *n'être de rien*, *servir de rien* (II.B.6.a,g), et même l'expression *de rien* en réponse à un remerciement.

Answer (score 1):

Je relis vos réponses* avec le recul (6 ans !), et il me semble au final que ce "de" est à rattacher à l'usage du mot "rien" (comme dans l'expression "rien de tout ceci"), c'est peut-être la forme larvée de

> Comme si *rien de ceci* n'était...

qui aurait subi une inversion

> Comme si[,] *de ceci*[,] *rien* n'était...

puis la disparition progressive du "ceci" qui alourdit la forme

> Comme si de rien n'était...

---

* (C'est le dernier point évoqué par Xaltar qui m'a suggéré cette réponse, merci à lui)

Answer (score 1):

Une explication possible se trouve peut-être dans cet extrait :

> *Mais c’est cela même qui est le principal artifice de votre conduite, de faire croire qu’**il y va de tout** en une affaire **qui n’est de rien**.* Blaise Pascal, *Les Provinciales*, 1657

Il faut comprendre *qui n'est constituée/créée/faite de rien*.

La préposition *de* serait alors proche de celle de l'expression toujours actuelle « ***de** rien du tout* » (insignifiant) comme dans :

> Un affaire **de** rien du tout.
>
> Un bobo **de** rien du tout.
>
> Il est **de** rien du tout, ton bobo.
>
> etc.

Comment: Intéressant. Ce qui reste cependant inexpliqué en suivant cette ligne d'analyse, c'est la négation. "Rien" appelle la négation : "Rien n'était.". En revanche, si le sujet (implicite) est "Une affaire de rien", la négation n'a plus sa place. Serait-ce une négation apparue "par erreur" à cause de l'euphonie due à la liaison "...rien_était..." ?

Comment: @RomainValeri Plutôt qu'une erreur, ce pourrait être un *ne* explétif comme dans *je le voyais plus grand qu'il n'était*.

Comment: @jiliagre Oui, merci, c'est tout-à-fait ça, le terme "explétif" ne m'était pas revenu :-)